# Excel copy from file to file macro not working

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I have to copy data from multiple excel files named with numbers (1.xlsx, 2.xlsx, 3.xlsx, etc). I wrote this macro. It runs. But no copy happens, the main workbook in which I ran the macro remains empty.

```vb
Sub filecopy()
' The macro is running in the main file, which I saved as .xlsm    
' This main.xlsm is in the same folder as the files from which I copy the data

Dim Filename As String, Pathname As String,xx as Double
Activesheet.Usedrange.Clear 'I delete the current contents of the sheet

Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")
xx = 1 'the first column where the contents of the first file goes

Do While Len(Filename) > 0
    
    Cells(1, xx).Formula = "='[" & Filename & "]Sheet1'!A1" 
    Cells(2, xx).Formula = "='[" & Filename & "]Sheet1'!B2"
    Cells(3, xx).Formula = "='[" & Filename & "]Sheet1'!C3"
    
    xx = xx + 1 'next file next column
    Filename = Dir() 
    Loop
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value 'every formula goes to value    
MsgBox "Work Complete", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Your current formula requires only the workbook name and the file to be open.  If you require the whole filename including the path to be looked up you should be using the following format `E:\My Data\Excel\[1.xlsx]Sheet1` You could refer to the attached code to get a list of all files in a folder http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/03/05/list-files-and-folders-in-a-directory/

Comment: The link also spilts the file name from the path and you need to use that to add the square bracket `[]` correctly as only the file name excluding the file path needs to have the square bracket.

Comment: @izzymo I think it's not allowed to post link where you first have to make a survey for viewing the content

Comment: @katz I dint get any survey when i opened the page. But will check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 errors in your code:

**1. `\` is missing -> `filename` is empty**

Replace `Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")` with `Filename = Dir(Pathname & "\*.xlsx")`

**2. the formula is not correct -> not complete filename**

Change your formulas e.g. `Cells(1, xx).Formula = "='[" & Filename & "]Sheet1'!A1"` with this `Cells(1, xx).Formula = "='" & Pathname & "\[" & Filename & "]Sheet1'!A1"`

Answer (score 0):

What about a solution like this:

```
Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path 'Be sure is the rigth path
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "\*.xlsx") 'I've addedd a "\"
xx = 1
Do While Len(Filename) > 0
    If Filename <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        Set mFile = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & "\" & Filename)
    Else
        GoTo NextFile
    End If
    With mFile.ActiveSheet 'Use the sheet you need here
        Cells(1, xx) = .Cells(1, 1).Value
        Cells(2, xx) = .Cells(2, 1).Value
        Cells(3, xx) = .Cells(3, 1).Value
    End With

    xx = xx + 1 'next file next column
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    mFile.Close savechanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set mFile = Nothing
NextFile:
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
```